# How to limit my Windows network transfer rate?

Tags: windows, networking, download, lan, http

Downloading a 2 MB file in my LAN using HTTP is going to fast, and I need to slow it down so I can debug one app I'm developing. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/135719/windows-program-to-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs

Comment: @flashnode answering that question also answers mine. but this one accepts a wider range of solutions.

Comment: Take a look at here:

http://serverfault.com/questions/14806/limit-transfer-speed-on-windows-2008

Comment: @Diogo_Rocha valeu cara.

Comment: @Jader Dias: Heheheheheh disponha :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I use NetBalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) to do this

Comment: I had to configure it properly to work with LAN transfers and below 80% bandwidth usage