# Is there a way in Windows 7 to throttle a program's bandwidth?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows program to limit bandwidth of other programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/135719/windows-program-to-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs)

In Windows 7, how can I limit the amount of bandwidth a program has access to?

I am downloading a TV episode using BBC iPlayer, and don't want to mess up the connection too much for my flatmate playing StarCraft II.

Comment: I think it's similar to this question at Superuser


http://superuser.com/questions/135719/windows-program-to-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs