# Automatic connection switch-over between two USB 3G dongles when transfer cap is reached?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

Is it possible to create a fault tolerance between two USB net sticks?

My 3G ISP only gives 3GB of traffic for a month, and when in stream a video from my outdoor cam it gets to the limit pretty fast (few days).

Is there a way to switch to another USB modem that I have from other provider when the first is out of bandwidth?

Comment: Good question, and welcome to Super User!

Comment: I would put emphasis on the fact that Super User *is not* a forum. ;)

Answer (score 0):

See the two top answers to the question ["Windows program to limit bandwidth of other programs?".](https://superuser.com/questions/135719/windows-program-to-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs).

#### First answer

> I use [NetBalancer](http://www.seriousbit.com/netbalancer/). While its a paid software, a free version exists, but can restrict traffic on upto 5 processes at a time.
>
> [image: Net Balancer Free]

#### Second answer

> I use [Net Limiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/), which is free.
>
> NetLimiter is an ultimate internet traffic control and monitoring tool designed for Windows. You can use NetLimiter to set download/upload transfer rate limits for applications or even single connection and monitor their internet traffic.
>
> Along with this unique feature, Netlimiter offers comprehensive set of internet statistical tools. It includes real-time traffic measurement and long-term per-application internet traffic statistics
>
> [image]

At the very least it seems that NetLimiter will allow you to limit the amount of data per network adapter, though I cannot personally vouch that it supports an automatic change to another adapter.