# How to Controll The Internet Usage For Each Application

Tags: windows, networking, internet

I am using windows 8.1. in my pc so many apps use internet  automatically when I am conected to the internet. I want to controll the application which can connect and which cannot. How to achieve this solution.

Comment: netbalancer,netlimiter were possible solutions where u could restrict per process

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I limit bandwidth of other programs?](http://superuser.com/questions/135719/how-can-i-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs)

Comment: It's hard to be sure, but it seems to me that this question is about how to *disable* network access on a per-process basis ("I want to control … which can connect and which cannot.") — i.e., firewall-type functionality —  and not how to limit bandwidth.

Comment: Ongoing discussion on exact topic at [How to Set Internet Usage Limit For Each Application](http://superuser.com/questions/973750/how-to-set-internet-usage-limit-for-each-application)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is the basic functionality of Windows Firewall: [Allow a program to communicate through Windows Firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)